# How to Call API Async using C# Like ajax below

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my jquery function to call a ssl api I want it to do using C#.
Is it possible same functionally in C#.
this jquery function working fine.

```
        $('#dvShowData').html("");
        $('#dvShowData').html("Loading...");
        var CommandParams = {
            login: 'str', 
            password: 'str',
            command: 'str',                  
            ssl_domain_name: 'str'
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'https://api.sslguru.com',
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: { params: JSON.stringify(CommandParams) },
            success: function (output) {
                // alert(output);
                $('#dvShowData').html("");
                $('#dvShowData').html(output);
            },
            error: function (output) {
                $('#dvShowData').html("");
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP request with post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

Comment: That's an automated link that Stack Overflow puts in there when someone suggests to close a question because it's already been answered.  It says "HTTP request with post".  Live dangerously - click it :)